# Sublime Text 3 curly brace auto-completion interferes with Emmet

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3, emmet

I'm new to Emmet and to Sublime Text 3.

In ST3, when I type the left curly brace, the right curly brace is automatically inserted, which interferes with Emmet i.e. when I type something like `a{Click Me}`, it expands to `a{Click <Me></Me>}` instead of the expected `<a href="">Click Me</a>`. However, if I delete the right curly brace and type the text I want, then manually insert the right curly brace, it expands correctly.

Any idea how I can fix this? Which setting do I need to change, if any? It's driving me mad. ¬ ¬

Comment: You can simply move caret after auto-closed brace and expand abbreviation. Or you can simply type `}`, Sublime Text is smart enough to not insert redundant brace.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I didn't realise expanding while my caret was inside the curly braces would cause an issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can:

- move caret after auto-closed brace and expand abbreviation, or
- type `}`.

Sublime Text is smart enough to not insert redundant brace.